# total removal and reinstall software

Tags: package-management, software-installation, permissions

I installed Kodi and made a mistake, tried to remove it and reinstall but it is coming back with the same settings. I found that after using `sudo` still there are some folders and 2 files that stayed. Because they are in root I cannot delete them. Any solution please?

Comment: you can do uninstallation with --purge flag which removes everything including config files

Comment: You can delete them via sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Kodi creates a `.kodi` folder for the user where all settings are kept.
What I would recommend is:

- Uninstall Kodi (if you followed their Ubuntu guide it should be `sudo apt-get remove kodi`)
- Delete any `.kodi/` directory for your user with `rm -rf ~/.kodi`
- Delete any `.kodi/` directory for the root user (as you indicate that also exists) `sudo su -` then `rm -rf ~/.kodi` then `exit`

Give it a quick look to make sure those folders no longer exist (if doing it through Nautilus you'll have to enable show hidden folders `CTRL-H` I believe.

Comment: It didn't work, I still has the Kodi files

Comment: Can you give more details -- how do you know there are more files ... and where? Please post a directory listing or something and I'll provide more.

Answer (score 0):

try Synaptic and use *Complete removal* feature:

1. Install Synaptic from Terminal using `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
2. Search for Kodi in the main window
3. mark all the packages that related with Kodi for Complete removal
4. Apply